# Como exibir o conteúdo de uma div com parâmetros em PHP

Tags: php, shell-script

Preciso de ajuda para atualizar o conteúdo dentro de uma div que é exibido como resultado em PHP.

Essa div contém variáveis em PHP para exibir os resultados que são tirados de um arquivo de texto que está em outro diretório. Tem como dar um auto refresh em alguns segundos (mesmo que seja em script ou Ajax, porém este precisa receber um parâmetro PHP para que o auto refresh pare quando a função em php acabar de ser executada) ?

Este é o conteúdo que contém na Div:

```
<div class="results">
  <?php
    //abrimos o arquivo em leitura
    $arquivo = 'log/speedtest.txt';
    $fp = fopen($arquivo, 'r');

    //lemos o arquivo
    $texto = fread($fp, filesize($arquivo));

    //transformamos as quebras de linha em etiquetas <br>
    $texto = nl2br($texto);

    echo $texto;
  ?>
</div>
```

E esta é a função que é executada em função do envio do formulário:

```
<?php

    if(isset( $_POST['submit'] )) {
        if( $_POST['ntestes'] == "0" ) {
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Último teste realizado.')</script>";
        }
        if($_POST['ntestes'] >= "1" ) {
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Testes realizados com sucesso!')</script>";
        }

        $ntestes = escapeshellarg($_POST["ntestes"]);

        $teste = shell_exec('/bin/speedtest ' .$ntestes. ' -l printf $?');

    }

?>
```

Este é o formulário que recebe os valores para execução da função em php acima:

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST" class="form">
  <p>
    <label>Número de testes: </label>
  </p>
  <select name="ntestes">
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1"selected>1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" class="execute" value="Executar">
  <a href="log/" class="btn" target="_blank">Visualizar Logs</a>
</form>
```

Alguma ideia de como posso fazer isso ?

Comment: A `div` está na página `log/`?

Comment: @AndreiCoelho Não, este log/ é uma outra página para exibir os logs apenas.

Comment: Tudo está na mesma página? Todos esses codigos?

Comment: @AndreiCoelho Sim, todo o código postado na pergunta é da mesma página.

Comment: E você quer que a div "results" fique atualizando, usando aquele código php que está dentro dela, é isso?

Comment: Isso, porém ela tem que parar quando a função em php terminar de ser executada.

Comment: Parar ela quando o `ntestes` for igual a `0`. É isso? Tem que parar quando terminar de rodar o speedtest

Comment: No caso quando a variável `$teste` for igual a `0` por isso coloquei o comando `shell_exec` dentro de uma variável. Esta variável receberá o valor como parâmetro da função executada.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97292/discussion-between-andrei-coelho-and-rooh-macedo).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conforme as conversas que tivemos, criei um script que deverá funcionar. Mas antes será necessário criar 2 arquivos no mesmo diretório do `index1.php`:

1 - **shell_test.php**

```
if(isset( $_POST['submit'] )) {

    $ntestes = escapeshellarg($_POST["ntestes"]);

    $teste = shell_exec('/bin/speedtest ' .$ntestes. ' -l printf $?');

}
```

Eu retirei os `if`s pois não entendi a necessidade deles.

2 - **result_list.php**

```
//abrimos o arquivo em leitura
$arquivo = 'log/speedtest.txt';
$fp = fopen($arquivo, 'r');

//lemos o arquivo
$texto = fread($fp, filesize($arquivo));

//transformamos as quebras de linha em etiquetas <br>
$texto = nl2br($texto);

echo $texto;
```

Abaixo, está o script completo. Fiz algumas alterações do html no arquivo `index1.php` e inseri o javascript no final dele. O código está comentado.

```
    <div class="results"></div>

    <form id="form-teste" class="form">
        <p>
            <label>Número de testes: </label>
        </p>
        <select name="ntestes">
            <option value="0">0</option>
            <option value="1"selected>1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="6">6</option>
            <option value="7">7</option>
            <option value="8">8</option>
            <option value="9">9</option>
        </select>
        <input type="button" name="submit" class="execute" value="Executar">
        <a href="log/" class="btn" target="_blank">Visualizar Logs</a>
    </form>

 <script type="text/javascript">

    var finish = false;

    // conexão com o servidor
    const httpObj = (callback, url, params) => {

        let req = new XMLHttpRequest();

        req.addEventListener('readystatechange', () => {

            if(req.readyState === 4 && req.status === 200)
                callback(true, req.responseText);
            else 
                callback(false, req.responseText);
        });

        req.open('POST', url);
        req.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        req.send(params);
    }

    // variaveis HTML (formulario e a div results)
    const form = document.querySelector('#form-teste');
    const res  = document.querySelector('.results');

    // quando o formulario fo submetido...
    form.submit.addEventListener('click', e => {

        e.preventDefault();
        finish = false;

        httpObj((status, result)=>{

            if(status) finish = true;

        }, 'http://ssie.com.br:8006/speedtest/shell_test.php', `nTestes=${form.ntestes.value}&submit=executar`);
    //      ^^ URL do script que será executado em php ----------------- ^^ dados do formulario via POST

        let timer = setInterval(() => {

            httpObj((status, result)=>{

                if(status) res.textContent = result;
                if(finish) clearInterval(timer);

            }, 'http://ssie.com.br:8006/speedtest/result_list.php', ``);
    //          ^^ URL do script que atualizará os testes na div results

        }, 2000); // atualiza a cada 2 segundos

    });

 </script>
```

Comment: Opa, desculpe a demora no retorno, verifiquei sua resposta já, porém não tive tempo de aplicar o resultado. Fiz conforme você passou, e, na verdade deu e não deu certo. O resultado agora não há quebra de linha, ele aparece a tag nos resultados `<br />`. Outro detalhe é que ao selecionar a quantidade '0' ele não retorna o último resultado executado e sim executa novamente o teste.

Comment: No dia seguinte que você me mandou a resposta eu já tinha conseguido a solução, mas mesmo assim estarei aplicando sua resposta como certa, pois ajudará outras pessoas também. Obrigado por dedicar um tempinho para me ajudar.

Comment: @RoohMacedo tranquilo amigo! Obrigado pela validação! Abraço!

Comment: @RoohMacedo AHHH! Eu não sabia que o "0" era para retornar o ultimo resultado.

Comment: @RoohMacedo sim... sempre tem alguns bugs para arrumar. É que como eu não tinha como fazer o teste, fiz meio que no "olhômetro".... rsrsrs....Valeu man!